# Operator Norm of a Linear Transformation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**PROBLEM** For the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ equipped with the $l^1$-norm, namely, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $||x||=\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|$ and similarly for $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, the operator norm is

$||T||_{op}=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^m |T_{ij}|$

Where the transform is defined to be matrix multiplication on left by matrix $T\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

---

My problem is that I don't understand how this follows from the definition of the operator norm, namely that $||T||_{op}=\sup_{||x||=1}||Tx||$, where I've tried to write down a proof.

**Work so far**: Not very far (I don't agree with statement intuitively). Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $T\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Following the definition of an operator norm,

$||T||_{op}=\sup_{||x||=1}||Tx||=\sup_{||x||=1}\sum_{i=1}^m|y_i|$ where $y_i=\sum_{j=1}^n T_{ij}x_j$.

Then $||T||_{op}=\sup_{||x||=1}\sum_{i=1}^m|\sum_{j=1}^n T_{ij}x_j|$

This is where I have no clue how to proceed. Is this the right direction, or should  I try another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead. Use triangle inequality, and interchange the summation. Then you find $||T||_{op}\le\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^m |T_{ij}|$. Let the max be attained at $j=j_0$. Now choose $x$ to be $e_{j_0}$.